# Using API Values as props to change State in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm using API Values primaryKey to change data represented on Click, but the function doesnt seem to work. and No Errors are thrown. I'm unable to find whats going wrong here.

What I'm trying to do here is -  By default the table outputs multiple stocks with multiple columns for each ,  when clicked on button
it should use the key value of that stock to represent only that single stock with its columns.
Here is my part of the code:

```
    handleClick = (props) => {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.data.filter(data => data.includes({props})).map(filteredData => (
                    <li>
                    {filteredData}
                    </li>
            ))};
            </div>
        );
    }
    renderArray = () => {
        return (
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Price/ Chng</th>
                        <th>Mkt Cap</th>
                        <th>Volume</th>
                        <th>Turnover</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.data.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={item.co_S}>
                                <button onCLick={this.setState = () => this.handleClick(item.co_S)}><td >{item.co_N}</td></button>
                                <td>{item.price}</td>
                                <td>{item.p_chng_pc}</td>
                                <td>{item.Mkt_cap}</td>
                                <td>{item.volume}</td>
                                <td>{item.volume * item.price}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })};
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <this.renderArray />
        )
    }
}

export default StocksHomePage2;
```

Comment: This question could use some clarity. Are you referring to the button with the `onClick` prop in your example code, and if so, what do you hope to achieve upon clicking the button, versus not clicking the button.

Comment: `onCLick={this.setState = () => this.handleClick(item.co_S)}`   this will be like `onCLick={ () => this.handleClick(item.co_S)}`

Comment: I have edited the question @CoryHarper

Comment: I tried your solution but it didnt work @MUHAMMADILYAS

Comment: `onCLick ` typo as well and the return result is not rendered anywhere you have to update the data it self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        co_S: 1,
        co_N: 1,
        price: 100,
        volume: 20,
      },
      {
        co_N: 2,
        co_S: 2,
        price: 30,
        volume: 7,
      },
    ],
  };

  handleClick = (props) => {
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.data.filter((item) => item.co_S === props),
    });
  };

  renderArray = () => {
    return (
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Price/ Chng</th>
            <th>Mkt Cap</th>
            <th>Volume</th>
            <th>Turnover</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.data.map((item) => {
            return (
              <tr key={item.co_S}>
                <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.co_S)}>
                  <td>{item.co_N}</td>
                </button>
                <td>{item.price}</td>
                <td>{item.p_chng_pc}</td>
                <td>{item.Mkt_cap}</td>
                <td>{item.volume}</td>
                <td>{item.volume * item.price}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return this.renderArray();
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @MUHAMMADILYAS